# How can I add Material Design Icons to my web project without loading Google Fonts?

Tags: html, css, entity-framework, get, frameworks

I want to avoid loading Google Fonts in a web project. Unfortunately "(get) MDL.io" only offers the linked content, in this case for the toggle icon of a mobile menu.
I have tried to download and relate some css files, how ever the toggle icon will not appearing.
Now I have downloaded the whole release, after moving the folder 'Android' to another drive, I have uploaded and related the whole folder material-design-icons-4.0.0. into the project folder even with adding 'src', just:

** What is the exact link () to "connect material-design-icons 4.0. without using the googleapis-link (https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons)?**

Because when using the Google link I get a warning that my side is using Google Fonts.

Until now the toggle icon won't be appearing, just the error square.

I have tried to relate the material-icon folder in the head area yet, after I have downloaded the files (.tar.gz file) and unpacked them successfully.

Following link should be replaced by a link to my server storage:

, what is correct path that the toggle icon of the mobile menu will be appearing when files are stored on own server?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.